# Agregar una imagen en un archivo pdf existente con php

Tags: php, pdf

Alguien tiene alguna idea de como agregar una firma a un archivo pdf existente con php.
Tengo un sistema de laboratorios donde se almacenan resultados de analisis en formato pdf y necesito insertar en el archivo firmas que tengo en formato de imagen para que los resultados sean válidos.

Como se puede hacer?

Comment: ¿Qué haz intentado hasta el momento?

Comment: Hasta ahora nada, hoy me surgio esta problematica. Estaba googleando y lo unico que encontre fue insertar un pdf existente a un nuevo pdf pero lo inserta como imagen y no me deja escribirle encima. solo por abajo o a los costados, lo que necesito es insertar sobre el documento mismo.

Comment: Seria bueno que agregaras el codigo actual que tienes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aunque a tu pregunta le hace falta trabajo de investigación te voy a dejar una respuesta ya que me pareció interesante tu pregunta

Basandome en esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586384/insert-images-files-in-existing-pdf-file-using-php) (*Insert images files in existing PDF file using PHP*) (*Insertar archivos de imagenes en un PDF existente usando PHP*) de SOen y este otro [link](https://pranavom.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/modify-pdf-using-fpdffpdi-library/), puedes hacer uso de las siguientes librerías [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) y [FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/downloads/) de la siguiente manera (ejemplo sumamente sencillo):

```
require_once('fpdf.php'); // Incluímos las librerías anteriormente mencionadas
require_once('fpdi.php'); // Incluímos las librerías anteriormente mencionadas

$pdf = new FPDI();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->setSourceFile("Ruta_de_mi_archivo_PDF"); // Sin extensión
$template = $pdf->importPage(1);
$pdf->useTemplate($template);
$pdf->Image('Ruta_de_mi_imagen.jpg', $x, $y, $width, $height);
$pdf->Output($nuevoNombreDelPDF, "F");
```

Donde las variables `$x` y `$y` son las coordenadas en donde poner la imagen dentro de tu PDF, `$width` y `$height` son el ancho y el alto respectivamente y por último la variable `$nuevoNombreDelPDF` que será el nombre de nuestro "nuevo" PDF

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda! Logre hacer lo que queria con tu respuesta, muy agradecido con todos. Una consulta mas, como puedo publicar el codigo para que aparezca en formato de "codigo" y no de comentario?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la clase FPDF para PHP, que se encarga de generar archivos PHP y la clase FPDI que se puede usar para importar archivos o páginas de archivos PDF pre-existentes.

Dale un vistazo a [ésto](https://rubayeet.wordpress.com/2010/02/05/modifying-pdf-files-with-php/)

Comment: Aunque el link puede ser útil, evita poner enlaces externos y trata de dar una respuesta aquí con un ejemplo, ya que estos enlaces se pueden romper

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, no lo había pensado. Por otra parte no me parece bien copiar el trabajo de otra persona y me parece muy respetable conservar la fuente original.